# ReferenceError: "Swal is not defined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, sweetalert

I'm working on small project using codeigniter and VueJs and sweet alert javascript library. but i get an error in my console `ReferenceError: "Swal is not defined"` once i call `swall.fire({})` inside my VueJs methods. 
**This is my code :**

```
deleteCustomers(customer_id){
        Swal.fire({
           title: 'Are you sure?',
           text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
           icon: 'warning',
           showCancelButton: true,
           confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
           cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
           confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
           }).then((result) => {
              axios.post('/Thirdparty/deleteCustomers', {id : customer_id}).then(function(response){
                 console.log(response.data);
                 //alert(response.data.error);
                 Swal.fire(
                 'Deleted!',
                 'Your file has been deleted.',
                 'success'
                 );
              });
           });
     }
```

and of course i have already imported swall using : `import Swal from 'sweetalert2';`

**NB** : swall.fire doesn't work only inside Vuejs methods

Comment: it is preferable that you use your own vue components, or maybe you can consider to use this one https://github.com/avil13/vue-sweetalert2 which has always worked well for me

Comment: i fixed the bug thank you,   solution is i had to do, window.Swol = import '';

Answer (score 18):

Here is a quick way to implement Sweet Alert on vue js

```
npm install sweetalert2
```

on your app.js register sweet alert to make it accessible in all your components

```
import swal from 'sweetalert2';
window.Swal = swal;
```

Then in any of the components of example ( Example.vue)

```
<template>
  ...
</template>
<script>
   export default{
     methods:{
       test(){
         Swal.fire('Test!', 'Hello test message','success');
      } 
    }
   }
```

More Sweet alert methods can be found [here](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#usage)

Answer (score 5):

`Swal` (with Capital S) and `Swal.fire()` is introduced in sweetalert2 version `> 7.20.0`.

In older versions (`< 7.20.0`), you should use `swal({options})` instead.

Also make sure to import it with capital S, if you're using npm :

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
```

Answer (score 4):

on your main.js register sweet alert to make it accessible in all your components

```js
import swal from 'sweetalert2';
window.Swal = Swal;
```